# Is it possible to create a search extension?

Tags: search, gmail, add-on

I want to create a search addon for Gmail (G Suite Marketplace).
I need to search mails by custom headers. Is it possible to add new features to search engine?

Answer (score 0):

No, from https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail:

> G Suite add-ons can define the following kinds of extensions within
>   Gmail:
>
> - Homepages and other non-contextual cards.
> - Contextual interfaces that appear when users open Gmail messages.
> - Contextual interfaces that appear when a user composes a message or reply.
> - Automatically create new message drafts in response to user interactions.

You may want to check instead the [Gmail APIs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering) to build a custom web app with [search capabilities](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) instead of a Gmail addon.